# Data type mismatch in criteria expression(Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to Display a name in the textbox from the database if the ID entered by the user matches the record in the MS ACCESS DATABASE.
I'm getting the error **Data type mismatch in criteria expression** at the line           `int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

The following is my aspx.cs code-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clear();
    idcheck();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dfg\fd\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite21\App_Data\UPHealth.mdb");

    con.Open();

    str = "SELECT [DoctorName] FROM [DoctorInfo] WHERE DoctorID='" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "'";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        TextBox2.Text = dr["DoctorID"].ToString();
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}

public void idcheck()
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dfg\fd\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite21\App_Data\UPHealth.mdb");
    con.Open();
    str = "SELECT count(DoctorName) FROM [DoctorInfo] WHERE DoctorID='" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    if (count > 0)
    {
        Label21.Text = "Doctor Name";
    }
    else
    {
        Label21.Text = "Id Does not Exist";
    }
}

void clear()
{
    TextBox2.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that is because you as passing in an ID, which is usually a numeric value, as a text field:

```
DoctorID='" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "'
```

Which should be:

```
DoctorID=" + TextBox1.Text.Trim()
```

Another problem arises, since you are vulnerable to SQL injection. What if the text box contained `1; delete users`? Then your entire users table would be empty. The lesson learned: use parameterized queries!

Then you can express the SQL as:

```
DoctorID= ?
```

And add the parameter to the request:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
```